# Django, post method not allowed (405) Detail View

Tags: django, django-forms

iam new to django, and trying to build a BLOG app.
The last step is to be able to create a comment in detail blog post, 
I tried to put the form for creating a comment in the same Detail View
as the blog_post and the comments,
when I try to create a comment with the form error shows up in console:
method post is not allowed, I tried everything but still doesnt work
please help , I highly appreciate yourhelp
MY CODE

VIEWS

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType



from .models import blog_post, Category
from .forms import blog_postForm


from comments.models import Comment
from comments.forms import CommentForm






class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = "blog/category_list.html"



class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        blogpost_set = obj.blog_post_set.all()
        default_blogpost = obj.default_category.all()
        blogposts = ( blogpost_set | default_blogpost ).distinct()
        context["blogposts"] = blogposts
        return context



class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
     @classmethod
     def as_view(cls, **kwargs):
       view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**kwargs)
       return login_required(view)

    #@method_decorator(login_required)
    #def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)



class blog_postCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    #model = blog_post
    form_class = blog_postForm
    template_name = "form.html"
    #fields = ["title", "content"]
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_post_list")

    # @method_decorator(login_required)
    # def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #   return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)    


class blog_postListView(ListView):

    model = blog_post
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(blog_postListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).order_by("-timestamp")
        return qs

class blog_postDetailView(DetailView):

    model = blog_post

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(blog_postDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        #default_blogpost = obj.default_category.all()
        #blogposts = ( blogpost_set | default_blogpost ).distinct()
        # content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(blog_post)
        # obj_id = obj.id
        # comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= obj_id)

        initial_data = {
            "content_type": obj.get_content_type,
            "object_id": obj.id
        }   

        form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
            content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
            obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
            content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
            new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            user = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            content = content_data
                        )

        comments = obj.comments.order_by("-timestamp")
        context['comments'] = comments
        context['comment_form'] = form
        return context



class AboutPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "about.html"


class ContactPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "contact.html"   



class IndexView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'home_list'    
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    queryset = blog_post.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

blog_post_detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}







{% block content %}


            <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <!-- Blog Post -->

                <!-- Title -->
                <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>

                <!-- Author -->
                <p class="lead">
                    by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </p>

                <hr>

                <!-- Date/Time -->
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on {{ object.timestamp|date }} </p>

                <hr>

                <!-- Preview Image -->
                <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt=""> -->
                        {% if object.image %}
                    <img src='{{ object.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
                        {% endif %}
                <hr>

                <!-- Post Content -->
                <div class="content-markdown"><p class="lead">{{ object.content }}</p></div>

                <hr>

                <!-- Blog Comments -->





                <!-- Comments Form LEAVE A COMMENT -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
 <!--                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form> -->
                        <form method="POST" action='.'> {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ comment_form }}
                        <input type='submit' value='Post comment' class='btn btn-default'>
                        </form>
                        <hr/>

                </div>

                <hr>

                <!-- Posted Comments -->
                <!-- Comment -->
                {% for comment in comments %}
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
<!--                         {% if object.image %}
                    <img src='{{ object.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
                        {% endif %} -->
                         <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt=""> 
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ comment.content_object }} 
                            <small> by {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago </small>
                        </h4>
                        {{ comment.content }}
                        <!-- Nested Comment -->
<!--                         <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Nested Start Bootstrap
                                    <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                                </h4>
                                Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                            </div>
                        </div> -->
                        <!-- End Nested Comment -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>


           <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <!-- Blog Search Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Search</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input-group -->
                </div>

                <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>

                <!-- Side Widget Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Side Widget Well</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
            {% endblock content %}
```

blog model

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.

from comments.models import Comment
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    #filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    #return "%s/%s.%s" %(instance.id, instance.id, extension)
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)


class blog_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True, width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title   

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_post_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    @property
    def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type





def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = blog_post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)



pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=blog_post)


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("category_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug })
```

comment model

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from django.db import models



#from blog.models import blog_post


class CommentManager(models.Manager):
    def filter_by_instance(self, instance):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        obj_id = instance.id
        qs = super(CommentManager, self).filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= obj_id)
        return qs



class Comment(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    #post        = models.ForeignKey(blog_post)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    content     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    objects = CommentManager()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

I highly appreciate yourhelp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add edit functionality to your view, you need to use `UpdateView` instead of `DetailView`

**Example**

```
class blog_postDetailView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    model = blog_post

    def get_initial(self):
        initial_data = super(blog_postDetailView, self).get_initial()
        obj = self.get_object()
        initial_data.update({
            "content_type": obj.get_content_type,
            "object_id": obj.id
        })
        return initial_data 

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(blog_postDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        #default_blogpost = obj.default_category.all()
        #blogposts = ( blogpost_set | default_blogpost ).distinct()
        # content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(blog_post)
        # obj_id = obj.id
        # comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= obj_id)
        comments = obj.comments.order_by("-timestamp")
        context['comments'] = comments
        # your form in template should be called form, doing this line for compatability
        context['comments_form'] = context['form']
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                        user = request.user,
                        content_type= content_type,
                        object_id = obj_id,
                        content = content_data
                    )
        return super(blog_postDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but i can not use the UpdateView instead of DetailView, cause error shows up then: 
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of blog_postDetailView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.

I guess its because, I want to be able that the users can create a comment on the "Detailview" template of the blog post, thats why still need to use the DetailView, 
what else i can do?

Comment: @RobertF. just add `form` to this view and it should be ok

Comment: i added form = commenForm to the DetailView, this you meant? But still the same, still in console when i wanna create a comment with the Form in the "Detail View" template (blog_post_detail.html) error: post method not allowed 405

Comment: @RobertF. No I meant add form to UpdateView

Comment: iam really sorry i dont get it exactly, could be so kind and post the fixed DetailVIew for / the code you mean, thanks a lot , spasibooooo :)

Comment: @RobertF. I should have been clearer. Read example. It may not work, but will give you basic idea. Ne za chto!

Comment: which example, i guess the view isnt a problem, but I still dont know how to fix it.... I tried it now with FormMixing and DetailView together, still not working, I have no idea why it doesnt work :(

Comment: @RobertF. I added example in my answer

Comment: oh... iam sorry, spasibo, i will try it out, thanks a lot :)

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: now this error comes, i already really appreciate your help, you know a solution for that ?

Comment: @RobertF. add full trace with errors. Currently I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: i made it working with fixing the code, i will upload the fixed code

Comment: **UpdateView** does't work for me either, but it's a different issue on **UpdateView**, because I'm using a form for a different model.

Answer (score 2):

I had to to use the forms.ModelForm. The only problem is now, i need to login to post/create
a comment successfully otherwise this error comes: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
Somebody has a solution for this?

VIEWS

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin

from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType



from .models import blog_post, Category
from .forms import blog_postForm


from comments.models import Comment
from comments.forms import CommentForm






class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = "blog/category_list.html"



class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        blogpost_set = obj.blog_post_set.all()
        default_blogpost = obj.default_category.all()
        blogposts = ( blogpost_set | default_blogpost ).distinct()
        context["blogposts"] = blogposts
        return context



class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
     @classmethod
     def as_view(cls, **kwargs):
       view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**kwargs)
       return login_required(view)

    #@method_decorator(login_required)
    #def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)



class blog_postCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    #model = blog_post
    form_class = blog_postForm
    template_name = "form.html"
    #fields = ["title", "content"]
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_post_list")

    # @method_decorator(login_required)
    # def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #   return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)    


class blog_postListView(ListView):

    model = blog_post

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(blog_postListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).order_by("-timestamp")
        return qs

# class blog_postDetailView(DetailView):

#     model = blog_post

#     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
#         context = super(blog_postDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
#         obj = self.get_object()
#         #default_blogpost = obj.default_category.all()
#         #blogposts = ( blogpost_set | default_blogpost ).distinct()
#         # content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(blog_post)
#         # obj_id = obj.id
#         # comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= obj_id)

#         initial_data = {
#             "content_type": obj.get_content_type,
#             "object_id": obj.id
#         }   

#         form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
#         if form.is_valid():
#             c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
#             content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
#             obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
#             content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
#             new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
#                             user = request.user,
#                             content_type= content_type,
#                             object_id = obj_id,
#                             content = content_data
#                         )

#         comments = obj.comments.order_by("-timestamp")
#         context['comments'] = comments
#         context['comment_form'] = form
#         return context



class blog_postDetailView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    model = blog_post
    template_name = 'blog/blog_post_detail.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial_data = super(blog_postDetailView, self).get_initial()
        obj = self.get_object()
        initial_data.update({
            "content_type": obj.get_content_type,
            "object_id": obj.id
        })
        return initial_data 

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(blog_postDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        #default_blogpost = obj.default_category.all()
        #blogposts = ( blogpost_set | default_blogpost ).distinct()
        # content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(blog_post)
        # obj_id = obj.id
        # comments = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id= obj_id)
        comments = obj.comments.order_by("-timestamp")
        context['comments'] = comments
        # your form in template should be called form, doing this line for compatability
        context['comments_form'] = context['form']
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                        user = self.request.user,
                        content_type= content_type,
                        object_id = obj_id,
                        content = content_data
                    )
        return super(blog_postDetailView, self).form_valid(form)








class AboutPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "about.html"


class ContactPageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "contact.html"   



class IndexView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'home_list'    
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    queryset = blog_post.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms



from .models import Comment

# class CommentForm(forms.Form):
#   content_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
#   object_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
#   #parent_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)
#   content = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea)

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='')  
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content_type','object_id', 'content'] # list of fields you want from model
        widgets = {'content_type': forms.HiddenInput(),'object_id': forms.HiddenInput(), 
       }
```

blog_post_detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}







{% block content %}


            <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-8">

                <!-- Blog Post -->

                <!-- Title -->
                <h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>

                <!-- Author -->
                <p class="lead">
                    by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </p>

                <hr>

                <!-- Date/Time -->
                <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on {{ object.timestamp|date }} </p>

                <hr>

                <!-- Preview Image -->
                <!-- <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt=""> -->
                        {% if object.image %}
                    <img src='{{ object.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
                        {% endif %}
                <hr>

                <!-- Post Content -->
                <div class="content-markdown"><p class="lead">{{ object.blog_content }}</p></div>

                <hr>

                <!-- Blog Comments -->





                <!-- Comments Form LEAVE A COMMENT -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
 <!--                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form> -->
                        <form method="POST" action='.' enctype='multipart/form-data'> {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form }}
                        <input type='submit' value='Post comment' class='btn btn-default'>
                        </form>
                        <hr/>

                </div>

                <hr>

                <!-- Posted Comments -->
                <!-- Comment -->
                {% for comment in comments %}
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
<!--                         {% if object.image %}
                    <img src='{{ object.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
                        {% endif %} -->
                         <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt=""> 
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ comment.content_object }} 
                            <small> by {{ comment.user }} | {{ comment.timestamp|timesince }} ago </small>
                        </h4>
                        {{ comment.content }}
                        <!-- Nested Comment -->
<!--                         <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Nested Start Bootstrap
                                    <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                                </h4>
                                Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                            </div>
                        </div> -->
                        <!-- End Nested Comment -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>


           <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <!-- Blog Search Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Search</h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.input-group -->
                </div>

                <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>

                <!-- Side Widget Well -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Side Widget Well</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
            {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add post method inside DetailView. like below:

```
  class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
         def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
```